# Mongoose - Deleting documents is unresponsive

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to use Mongoose (MongoDB JS library) to create a basic database, but I can't figure out how to delete the documents / items, I'm not sure what the technical term for them is.

Everything seems to work fine, when I use `Item.findById(result[i].id)`, it returns a valid id of the item, but when I use `Item.findByIdAndDelete(result[i].id)`, the function doesn't seem to start at all.

This is a snippet the code that I have: (Sorry in advance for bad indentation)

```
const testSchema = new schema({
    item: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    detail: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    quantity: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
})

const Item = mongoose.model("testitems", testSchema)



        Item.find()
           .then((result) => {
                for (i in result) {
                    Item.findByIdAndDelete(result[i].id), function(err, result) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err)
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log("Deleted " + result)
                        }
                    }
                }
                mongoose.connection.close()
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err)
            })
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, and I haven't been able to find anything on the internet.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`_id` is a special field on MongoDB documents that by default is the type [`ObjectId`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/bson-types/#std-label-objectid). Mongoose creates this field for you automatically. So a sample document in your `testitems` collection might look like:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("..."),
  item: "xxx",
  detail: "yyy",
  quantity: "zzz"
}
```

However, you retrieve this value with `id`. The reason you get a value back even though the field is called `_id` is because Mongoose creates a [virtual getter](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/virtuals.html#mongoose-virtuals) for [`id`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#id):

> Mongoose assigns each of your schemas an `id` virtual getter by default which returns the document's `_id` field cast to a string, or in the case of ObjectIds, its hexString. If you don't want an `id` getter added to your schema, you may disable it by passing this option at schema construction time.

The key takeaway is that when you get this value with `id` it is a string, *not* an `ObjectId`. Because the types don't match, MongoDB will not delete anything.

To make sure the values and types match, you should use `result[i]._id`.